# Cabal-install installs old package versions by default

Tags: haskell

I just upgraded to the latest version of cabal-install which is 1.20. I am not sure if it is related but cabal started fetching old versions of packages for some reason.

In my cabal file, all dependencies are specified without version numbers. So I believe, cabal should fetch the latest versions available unless there is a conflict, correct?

If I run `cabal install --only-dependencies` within a sandbox environment, cabal pulls all kind of rubbish and old package versions like mongoDB-1.2.2 instead of 1.4.4 and scotty-0.5 instead of 0.7.2. If I run a specific package installation like `cabal install scotty` then it fetches the latest version and all is well. So I have to install all dependencies manually to get the latest versions - one by one. Annoying. What is going on?
Google gives me no hits.

If there are some kind of changes in cabal, what is it? And how do I pull all the latest dependencies within a sandbox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your dependencies have upper bounds that are forcing the usage of older versions of a given package. One thing that might help is to start over. Delete your package repository (~/.ghc on linux machines), and keep a discipline to work entirely within sandboxes. Use your package manager to install stuff you need globally, sandboxes for your development projects, and you can avoid a lot of the reasons this problem crops up. That said, if you're truly depending on a project that hasn't updated its upper bounds, then you're stuck using the older packages, short of submitting a patch to the library author or switching to a different dependency.